# What happens if/when DllImport is invoked multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, dllimport

I am loading a .dll written in Delphi 7 using DllImport within a Windows service written in C# .NET 4.  Before deploying this service, I just want to make sure that I don't have to do anything special to handle the unmanaged .dll.

My C# code looks something like this:

```
[DllImport("MyDelphiDLL.dll")]
private static extern string DoSomething(string value);

private void SomeMethod(List<string> values)
{
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        string newValue = DoSomething(value);
    }
}
```

The `DoSomething` function will be called multiple times, and I *suspect* that MyDelphiDLL.dll only gets loaded either when the managed .dll gets loaded, or upon the first reference to DoSomething, but I'm not really sure.

I have looked at the [DllImportAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) documentation at MSDN, but it doesn't really state one way or the other.  I've also searched SO, and Googled the question every way that I can think of, and still haven't found a definitive answer.

I just want to make sure I go about this correctly.

Comment: It only gets loaded once, happens on the first call to the function.

Comment: @HansPassant any reference which said that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There no problem with what you're doing. The DLL will be loaded once and will stay loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I think your dll will be loaded once. DllImport is only point for compiler to generate code for DoSomething method in special manner instead of compiling method body it to IL.

Also in deep underlying it seems call LoadLibrary WinAPI method that loads dll only once. I'm not sure it is possilbe to load dll multiple times in bounds of one process.